# Can't access session from error pages in PHP

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter framework and I need to access the session from 404 error page.

My page is in `/application/errors/`

I want to the access session to check the user data to take decision.

```
<?php
if ($this->session->userdata('fUserId') != '') {
    include('header.php');
} else {
    include('header_without_login.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: have you print_r session data  on 404 and other pages? is session data set or not?

Comment: its working  the other place  put not in error pages

Comment: can the place  of error pages effect

Answer (score 0):

I think you should specify session library in autoload.php

There is no special to 404 page